# HTTP status code for failed serialization

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I have a GET /v2/developer/jhUxad8 endpoint which get developer from database and serialize it to json.

What http status code should I return when serialization fail?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

> What http status code should I return when serialization fail?

If I'm understanding you correctly, the server understands the request, and is trying to fulfill it, but because of a data problem is unable to do so.

[500 Internal Server Error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1)

> The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.